# bloquear link de imagem para outros sites

Tags: apache, htaccess

Galera tenho a seguinte pasta na raiz do meu site:

```
Arquivos/Fotos/goto1.jpg
```

Se eu digitar no navegador o link co meu site (www.meusite.com.br/Arquivos/Fotos/goto1.jpg) a foto se abre, e possível bloquear isso? Ou seja permitir que a foto só seja exibida dentro das páginas do meu site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível!

Você pode tentar o seguinte no **.htaccess** (Apache):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Você pode fazer o mesmo no IIS usando Web.config, mas eu não sei como se faz.

O exemplo acima, usando o Apache, tem o localhost como domínio, **certifique-se de usar o domínio correto** no lugar de "`localhost`".

Comment: Oi, eu tentei usar isso no meu htacess, porém nem o meu site esta abrindo as fotos. O que pode ser?

Comment: Veja a lista de extensões, por favor. Eu listei apenas duas: .gif e .jpg Abraço

Comment: bom pelo o que eu entendi era para o gif e jpg ser lida apenas pelo html do meu site, correto? isso não ocorre, quando uso o código que vc me passou ele bloqueia a imagem para meu site tbm, como se a imagem não existisse.