# Como restringir requisições GET vindas de outros site?

Tags: htaccess, apache, get, request, mod-rewrite

Estou tentando impedir que outros sites copiem meus links de download, mas eles não são convencionais (não possuem formato no final), então não consigo bloquear através do mod_rewrite do Apache.

Então resolvi bloquear requisições GET vindas de outros sites, mas as formas que testei estão bloqueando todas as requisições, inclusive do site que eu estou tentando permitir.

O que tentei sem sucesso foi:

```
<Limit GET> 

order allow,deny
Allow from exemplo.com
Deny from all

</Limit>
```

Comment: Já respondido em [bloquear link de imagem para outros sites](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142623/bloquear-link-de-imagem-para-outros-sites) - Mas cuidado: pode ser desejável aceitar _referrer_ em branco também.

Comment: Segue o seguinte https://serverfault.com/questions/270950/only-allow-get-request-with-htaccess - Os filtros de ALLOW de DENY você altera

Answer (score -1):

Posso está certo ou errado, porém acho que fazer download de arquivos depende muito do que seja, exemplo, CSS, JS, tudo dá pra ser baixado e se o cara achar algum .exe, .rar, .png, algo que ela consiga abrir link, será baixado do mesmo jeito, então acho meio desnecessário você tentar bloquear algo, que a própria net faz o cara baixar, principalmente dando view-source: no seu site.

Comment: Eu não quero esconder os downloads, quero que eles sejam bloqueados nos sites que não forem os meus, pois estão consumindo muita banda minha. O formato dos downloads é exemplo.com/XXX/download. Ou seja, não tem formato. Só quero impedir que a pessoa copie o HTML do meu site e cole em outro site.

Comment: entendi, então seria mais fácil você utilizar .htaccess como link normal. Exemplo: RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$ exemplo.com/$1/download prático e simples.

Comment: Você poderia me passar o código completo de como eu deveria inserir no .htaccess?

Comment: claro, vou te enviar:

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/download?$ index.php?download=$1&arquivo=download

Comment: você colocará no .htaccess e organizará a downloads.php formate de acordo com seu site, lembre-se será necessário 2 GET dentro da página download, 1º a ?download=ARQUIVO e a 2º &arquivo=download ou true